# Hide console in eclipse

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

It is posible to create a project with no console in Eclipse? Or can I hide it so it doesnt appear at all ?
I tried ShowWindow(), FreeConsole() but the console still appears for a fraction of a second. I also tried using WinMain,still no change. I know that I can do it in VS2010 by creating a Windows Application(not console), but it is posible in Eclipse too ?

Comment: You should add some tag that this is a windows-specific question.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=26476

Comment: i already read that site, its no good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has to be passing `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` to the linker, if using `WinMain` is still giving you a console. Look in the settings for an option to change the parameters it invokes `cl` with and change `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` to `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`.

Comment: Hey @vBx, you accepted the answer, so it might have worked for you, cool. But I would like to know where exactly did you set /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS on eclipse, because I can't find it. Thks